# How do wpf control template triggers work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate

I have seen a control template for tab control...in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookNavi.aspx

1. Is this property triggers  ? (Not data/event triggers)
2. Is this trigger works this way - if TabStripPlacement is "Bottom"...all Setters will be executed ?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*" />
        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource
            {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes, except that "executed" may be the wrong word here, more accurate would be: While TabStrinpPlacement is Bottom, the setters are active. (i.e. if the value changes to something else the previous values will be used again, see also: [DP Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))