# Why is "<ControlTemplate.Triggers>" not recognized or accessible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to change the style of some buttons when they were clicked (`IsPressed`) (e.g. change `BorderThickness` to `1, 1, 1, 0`). I've tried `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` but there is an error: "The member 'Trigger' is not recognized or accessible".
Here is my code I've got:

```
<UserControl
<!-- ... -->
>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2, 2, 2, 1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers> <!-- Here is the error -->
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2, 2, 2, 0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <!-- some definitions --> 
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="1" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="2" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="3" />
</Grid>
```

How can I handle that the style changes when the button is clicked and apply the style?

**EDIT**: Filled "//..." with code

Comment: WPF or Silverlight? Silverlight doesn't support `ControlTemplate` triggers, you'd have to use the `VisualStateManager`...

Comment: @minimen to animate `BorderThickness` with `VisualStateManager` you would need `ThickenssAnimation` and unfortunately Silverlight doesn't even have that

Comment: @dkozl Is there no other way? I'd likt to handle that in pure XAML

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop I'm using WPF, any ideas how to get that work?

Comment: @RoelvanWesterop Why does `ControlTemplate.Triggers` work for others but not for me? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034009/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-target-an-element-type-in-a-controltemplates-trigger), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341711/how-do-wpf-control-template-triggers-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237890/wpf-ispressed-trigger-of-controltemplate-not-working)

Comment: @minimen It works for me, but I can't tell why it doesn't work for you, please post a more complete example (fill in the //... above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recognized nor accessible because it's not supported in Silverlight. Please refer to this MSDN-Article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx